# How to turn tel: protocol into URL?

Tags: .htaccess, ms-office, github-pages, tel

I am using an MS Office to make a PDF presentation. And MS office does not support tel: links. So I made a htaccess redirection to tel:[phone number] that worked but now I switched to GitHub pages to host the website and and Github does not support htaccess redirections.

I have also tried jamming tel: protocol into URL shorteners they do not recognise it as a URL.

Do you have any 3rd party methods I could use to make a URL that redirects to tel: protocol URI ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though Github Pages doesn't allow `htaccess`, the [service does allow redirects from the Jekyll Plugin](https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/). Also, the [Jekyll Redirect plugin allows you to customize the redirect template](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from#customizing-the-redirect-template), which may allow the `tel` links that you're looking for.

P.S. Interesting question! When I first looked at it, I didn't think it was possible, but now, I think it is.